# How to connect to Community Edition Databricks Cluster via Outside Public Address / Application

Tags: networking, databricks, databricks-community-edition

Can someone let me know if its possible to connect or PING a Databricks Cluster via its public ip address?

For example I have issued the command ping --all-ip-addresses and I get the ip address 10.172.226.115.

I would like to be able to PING that ip address(10.172.226.115) from my on-premise PC (or connect to the cluster with an application using the ip address?

Can someone let me know if that is possible?

Comment: I just tested pinging to 8.8.8.8 from the cluster and it was successful. Therefore, I'm certain that I can ping the cluster from my PC, just not sure how to get the public ip address of the cluster. On reflection 10.172.226.115 is a private ip address whereas I need th public ip address of the cluster. Any thoughts on how to get the public ip address would be great

Comment: ok, so I've managed to get the public ip address of the cluster, now I just need advice on how successfully ping the ip address?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That public IP is not guaranteed to be **your** cluster; unless somehow you've installed Databricks into your own cloud provider account, where you fully control the network routes, it would be connecting to Databricks managed infrastructure where the public ip would likely be an API gateway or router that serves traffic for more than one account

Note: just because you can ping Google DNS with outbound traffic doesn't mean inbound traffic from the internet is even allowed through the firewall

> connect to the cluster with an application

I'd suggest using other Databricks support channels (i.e their community forum) to see if that's even possible, but I thought you're just supposed to upload and run code within their ecosystem. At least, for the community plans

Specifically, they have a [REST API](https://docs.databricks.com/dev-tools/api/latest/jobs.html) to submit a remote job from your local system, but if you want to be able to send data back to your local machine, I think you'd have to write and download from DBFS or other cloud filesystem